# Sequential ajax queries with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've spent quite a while trying to figure this out with various iterations of code, but with no luck. Coming from a php background I am new to javascript.

assume an array of three patches: patch1, patch2, patch3.
What I'm trying to achieve is:

1. an ajax call to the same php script for each patch, *but each call must be made only after the previous call is completed*
2. After all 3 are complete an ajax call to a separate php script is made.

Point 2 is working fine, point 1 not so.

Below is my code: the myAjaxInitialData func (and the underlying php script) is being called simultaneously for all 3 patches, rather than waiting for each to complete. The myAjaxGetSRCount is, correctly, not being called unitl all the patches are complete.

```
<body onload="initialData(0)">

<script>
function initialData(i) {

    var patches = [<?php echo $jsPatchArray ?>];
    var x = patches.length - 1;

    var divId = "#initialData-patch-" +i;
    var script = "ajax_initial_data.php";
    var dataVar = "patch";
    var data = patches[i];

    if ( i != x) {
        i++;
        $.when(myAjaxInitialData(divId,script,dataVar,data)).then(initialData(i));
    } else {
        $.when(myAjaxInitialData(divId,script,dataVar,data)).then(myAjaxGetSRCount);
    }   
}


function myAjaxInitialData(divId,script,dataVar,data ) {

    return $.ajax({ 
        type: "GET",
        url: script,
        data: {patch:data},
        success: function( response ) {     
            $( divId ).html( response );
        }
    }); 
}

function myAjaxGetSRCount() {

    document.getElementById('srCount').innerHTML="Retrieving SR Counts..";

    $.ajax({ 
        type: "GET",
        url: "ajax_sr_count.php",
        success: function( response ) {
            $( "#srCount" ).html( response ); 
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be here:

```
$.when(myAjaxInitialData(divId,script,dataVar,data)).then(initialData(i));
```

`then` takes a callback, i.e. a function. `initialData(i)` doesn't return anything so you are passing `undefined` into this function. If you mean to call `initialData` after this ajax request then you need to wrap it in a parameter-less function.

```
$.when(myAjaxInitialData(divId,script,dataVar,data)).then(function() { initialData(i); });
```

You should also be very aware that the value of `i` will be the value *at the time of the callback*. When closing over iterator variables, you should capture the value you expect before you create the callback. I.e.

```
if (i != x) {
    i++;
    var j = i;
    $.when(myAjaxInitialData(divId,script,dataVar,data)).then(function() { initialData(j); });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim - worked a treat - can't pretend to understand the `function() { initialData(j); }` vs plan old `initialData(j)` but that's no doubt due to js noobie status - will reasearch some more.

Comment: @DaveF The latter executes `initialData` with `j` as a parameter; the former creates a function that does the same. It works because you don't want to execute `initialData` immediately; you want tell something else to execute it when it's done.